# Fire base app crashed after publishing on play store

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my app is working well on my first phone in which I used to run tests. But it crashed after uploading on Play store and used in another phone. Why does this happen? [firebase]

I had changed the package name of the app in source code. So I added a new app on Firebase and used it's json source file too

I can sign in successfully but then it crashes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes when fetching data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696008/app-crashes-when-fetching-data)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i experienced this issue and solved it by setting `minified enabled` to `false` in gradle.

Apparently this only got to happen when i upload the apk to appstore, was using firebase 9.6.0.